# Need help understanding compact embedding of hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to understand the following statement, and I would like some clarification

> Consider a Hilbert space $H$ which is compactly embedded in a Hilbert space $L$, with $H^*$ being the dual space of $H$ with respect to the inner product (duality pairing) in $L$.

First of all, let me write $\|\cdot\|_H$ for the norm induced by the inner product of $H$, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$, let $\|\cdot\|_L$ be analogously defined for $L$.

Then, I understand that $H$ being compactly embedded in $L$ means (from wikipedia) that

> (i) There exists a constant C such that $\|x\|_L ≤ C\|x\|_H$ for all x in $H$
>
> (ii) Every bounded sequence in $H$ has a subsequence which is Cauchy in the norm $\|\cdot\|_L$.

But then,  as fas as I know, the dual space of $H^*$ is the set of continuous linear functions from $H$ to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e.

$$H^* = \{f:H \to \mathbb{R} \mid \exists C \text { such that } |f(x)| \leq C\|x|_H \text { for every } x \in H\}.$$ So, what does it mean to say that  $H^*$ being dual space of $H$ with respect to the inner product (duality pairing) in } $L$?

Comment: Please do not put stuff in \text{...} if you do not need to. It makes it hard to read your post. Simply use single dollar signs if you want to write something in $\rm\LaTeX$. Also use * instead of \star when discussing the dual space. Lastly, use \langle and \rangle in place of < and > when writing inner products.

Comment: How did you put the texts in coloured boxes?

Comment: Use > right before your text and it'll appear like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H^*$ is indeed the set of continuous linear functionals on $H$.  I think what they mean here is that each member $y$ of $L$ induces a linear functional $x \to \langle y, x\rangle_L$ on $H$ (here I'm using the convention that the inner product is linear in the second variable), which is in $H^*$ since
$|\langle y, x\rangle_L| \le \|y\|_L \|x\|_L \le C \|y\|_L \|x\|_H$.
So we identify $H^*$ as a space containing $L$, and the pairing of $H^*$ with $H$ is compatible with the inner product of $L$ in that the two coincide when the member of $H^*$ is in $L$.

EDIT: It may help to look at an example.

Let $L$ be the sequence space $\ell^2$ with its usual inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_j \overline{x_j} y_j$.

Let $H = \{x \in \ell^2: \sum_j j |x_j|^2 < \infty\}$, with the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle_H = \sum_j j \overline{x}_j y_j$.

A bounded linear functional on $H$ can be written
as $\phi(x) = \sum_j \phi_j x_j$; this is OK as long as 
$\sum_j |\phi_j|^2/j < \infty$.  But we might not have
$\sum_j |\phi_j|^2 < \infty$ (e.g. try $\phi_j = j^{-\alpha}$ where $1/2  \ge \alpha > 0$), so $\phi$ does **not** have to come from a member of $L$ via the inner product of $L$.

Comment: Could you tell me more on what you mean by "the pairing of $H^*$   with $H$  is compatible with the inner product of L  in that the two coincide when the member of $H^*$   is in $L$ ?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is that : if I let $A = \{\langle y, \cdot \rangle _L : y \in L\}$, the set of all induced linear functionals, then as you said $A \subset H^*$, but how do I see that $H^* \subset A$ ?

Comment: You don't, because it isn't.

Comment: It just came to me that $H$ being compactly embedded in $L$ is sufficient to give that every member $y$ of $L$ induces a functional in $H^*$ using  the inner product of $L$. So, in fact, there is no need( redundant) to say "the pairing of $H^*$   with $H $ is compatible with the inner product of $L$ in that the two coincide when the member of $H^*$  is in $L$  ?